# How to detect modification of nested object in Python?

Tags: python, object, magic-methods

Say I have something like this (not tested):

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.store = {}

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.store[key] = value
        print('Detected set')

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.store[key]
```

`__setitem__` is only called when the object itself is changed:

```
 foo = Foo()
 foo['bar'] = 'baz'
```

But it is not called, for example, when:

```
 foo['bar'] = {}
 foo['bar']['baz'] = 'not detected inside dict'
```

How can I detect this kind of case, or is there some other way I should be doing this? My goal is to have a dictionary-like object that is always in-sync with a file on disk.

Comment: Could the nested object be aware of its "parent"? You can't do this with a regular dictionary, but could with a custom mapping.

Comment: @stellasia that's not a great idea, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/3001761

Comment: Related Mutation tracking in nested JSON structures using SQLAlchemy  http://variable-scope.com/posts/mutation-tracking-in-nested-json-structures-using-sqlalchemy

Comment: Dict-like object which is in sync with file? Sounds like https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html if you open with `writeback=True` and then regularly call `sync` you should be fine.

Comment: Maybe change this `foo['bar'] = {}; foo['bar']['baz'] = 'not detected inside dict'` to this `foo['bar'] = Foo(); foo['bar']['baz'] = 'detected inside dict'`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `shelve`. I provides a persistent dictionary.
Opening a file with `writeback=True` forces synchronization with the file:

```
db = shelve.open('test.db', writeback=True)
```

Treat it just like a dict:

```
>>> db['a'] = {}
>>> db['a']['x'] = 10
>>> dict(db)
{'a': {'x': 10}}
```

Close an re-open:

```
>>> db.close()
>>> db = shelve.open('test.db', writeback=True)
>>> dict(db)
{'a': {'x': 10}}
```

The data is still there.

Comment: Note however that sync is only done when you explicitly call it (which is also done on close). If your program crashes after last change and before next sync, the data is lost.